# Controlling max and min zoom with PinchGesture

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having issues figuring out where to put an if/or statement with a max/min Scale to control how far you can zoom in and out of my GameScene in Xcode(Swift). I tried limiting the sender.scale but due to this number changing based on the starting point of when you zoom I can't get it to work. Below is my relevant code.

```
@objc func pinchGestureAction(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    let maxScale = CGFloat(1.0)
    let minScale = CGFloat(0.1)

    guard let camera = self.camera else
    {
        return
    }

    if sender.state == .began
    {
        previousCameraScale = camera.xScale
    }

        camera.setScale(previousCameraScale * 1 / sender.scale)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following lines to the end of your function:

```
camera.xScale = min(maxScale, camera.xScale)
camera.yScale = min(maxScale, camera.yScale)
camera.xScale = max(minScale, camera.xScale)
camera.yScale = max(minScale, camera.yScale)
```

Hope this helps!